# Can't plot DSolve's solution to Riccati differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

DSolve gives a strange solution for the Riccati differential equation  $ y' = (y^2) - 2 x^2 y + (x^4) + 2 x + 4  $

```
Opres = DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^2-2x^2*y[x]+x^4+2x+4, y[x], x]
```

$\left\{\left\{y(x)\to \frac{1}{c_1 e^{4 i x}-\frac{i}{4}}+x^2-2 i\right\}\right\}$

When I try plot this solution

```
Opresgraf = 
 Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. Opres /. C[1] -> Range[-3, 3]], {x, -4.7, 4.7}, 
  PlotRange -> 4.7]
```

I get a blank graph.

My question is: how can I get a solution with `DSolve` (not with `NDSolve`, because in my student research project I need `DSolve`) and plot that solution, the most important is to plot that general solution with `DSolve`.

Comment: You can't plot a complex expression. You need to either plot its real value, its imaginary value or its modulus. Also you have a typo in the input, you need `y[x]` not `y` in the ODE itself.

Comment: Is `Range[-3.3]` supposed to be `Range[-3,3]`?

Answer (score 8):

perhaps

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm@y[x] /. (Opres /. C[1] -> Range[-3, 3])], {x, -4.7, 4.7}, 
  PlotRange -> 4.7]
```

[image]

Comment: But is the solution of d.e only real , will y[x]-> Complex even be solution of d.e and what will be Derivate of that y[x] complex ?

Answer (score 5):

With a single graph you can only plot those solution that are imaginary or real.

<s>There are 2 real ones:</s>

```
sol = First[DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, y[x], x]];
zeroIm = FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Im[y[x] /. sol]]] == 0 // Solve[#, C[1]] &
```

> $\style{text-decoration:line-through}{\left\{\left\{C[1]\to -\frac{1}{4}\right\},\left\{C[1]\to \frac{1}{4}\right\}\right\}}$

I forgot to consider complex values of `C[1]`:

```
sol = First[DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, y[x], x]];
zeroIm = Numerator[FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Im[y[x] /. sol], C[1]]]] == 0

(* -2 + 32 Abs[C[1]]^2 == 0 *)
```

which is the equation of a circle of real solutions:

```
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> Sqrt[1/16] (Cos[t] + I Sin[t])],
               {x, -4.7, 4.7}, Exclusions -> All], {t, 0, 2 π}]
```

[image]

Code for GIF-animation:

```
n = 70;
pics = Table[Rasterize[#, "Image"] & @ Plot[
        Evaluate[y[x] /. sol /. C[1] -> Sqrt[1/16] (Cos[t] + I Sin[t])], {x, -4.7, 4.7},
        PlotRange -> {{-4.7, 4.7}, {-30, 46}}, ImageSize -> {500, 300}, AspectRatio -> Full,
        PlotRangePadding -> None, PlotRangeClipping -> True,
        ClippingStyle -> False], {t, 0, 2 π - #, #}] &[2 π/n];
Export["asd.gif", pics, "AnimationRepetitions" -> ∞,
        "ColorMapLength" -> 16, "DisplayDurations" -> ConstantArray[0.04, n]]
```

Comment: With what function you get that last graph ?

Comment: @МилошВучковић I haven't saved it but I have added something similar except for adding the text row to the images.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
Opres = DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]^2-2x^2 *y[x]+x^4+2x+4, y[x], x][[1]];
Plot[{Re[y[x]/.Opres/.C[1]->Range[3.3]],Im[y[x]/.Opres/.C[1]->Range[3.3]]}, {x,-4.7,4.7}]
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is not real valued.  Try setting an initial condition:

```
FullSimplify[
 DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, y[0] == 1}, 
   y[x], x]
]
```

yielding

```
{{y[x] -> -2 I + (4 + 8 I)/((2 - I) + (2 + I) E^(4 I x)) + x^2}}
```

which is not real valued (almost everywhere).  However, for a different initial condition

```
FullSimplify[
  DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, y[0] == 0}, 
    y[x], x]
]

{{y[x] -> x^2 + 2 Tan[2 x]}}
```

the solution is real valued.

We can use a symbolic initial condition

```
FullSimplify[
  DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, y[0] == c}, 
    y[x], x]
]

{{y[x] -> -2 I + (8 - 4 I c)/(-2 I - c + (-2 I + c) E^(4 I x)) + x^2}}
```

and see that this complex valued behaviour is generic, but can be hidden with particular choices of the initial condition, `c`.  Note that we can give the initial condition at a different value of the independent variable, and get different behaviour altogether.  In fact, providing an initial condition at `x=1` gives a real valued generic solution.

```
FullSimplify[
  DSolve[{y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, y[1] == c}, 
    y[x], x]
]

{{ y[x] -> ( 2 (-1 + c + x^2) Cos[2 - 2 x] + (-4 + (-1 + c) x^2) Sin[2 - 2 x] )/
  ( 2 Cos[2 - 2 x] + (-1 + c) Sin[2 - 2 x] ) }}

Plot[Table[y[x] /. %[[1]], {c, -2, 2}], {x, -2, 2}]
```

[image: Plot of several particular solutions.]

---

Starting over in full generality, we can get an unintelligible plot.

```
genSol = FullSimplify[ ComplexExpand[
  y[x] /. DSolve[{
    y'[x] == y[x]^2 - 2 x^2*y[x] + x^4 + 2 x + 4, 
    y[d] == c}, 
    y[x], x][[1]]
]];
Plot[Flatten[
  Table[genSol, {c, -20, 20, 10}, {d, -2, 2, 1}
  ], 1], {x, -4, 4}]
```

[image: Much too busy plot]

Here we have applied the generic initial condition $y(d) = c$ (via `y[d] == c`) so that we have labels for the parts of a point of a particular solution.  Since we only want real solutions, we want $c$, $d$, and $x$ to be real.  Applying `ComplexExpand[]` treats all the variables as if they are real, yielding real solutions passing through the point $(c,d)$.  (The largest effect here is that the complex exponentials are rewritten in terms of sine and cosine.)

Comment: And is this on the end "REAL" GENERAL SOLUTION which will include all reals solution that that General solution ?

Comment: No.  As explained, setting different `y[d]==c` will produce different solutions.  The last one has `d` fixed at `1`.  Varying both `c` and `d` at once will produce all the real solutions and also yield an unintelligible graph.  I'll add more about this.

Comment: Wait, you took for c , -20,-10,0,10,20  and for d -2,-1,0,1,2 ? 
And for that how we know fore sure that will be for all that c and d reals solutions and what we get with this ? It's just many real solutions, but still not all real solutions--> General Solutions  ?

Comment: @МилошВучковић : Every real solution passes through at least one real point of the plane.  Consequently, varying `c` and `d` through every real point of the plane will produce every solution (with infinitely many repetitions since every point on any particular solution is one of the initial conditions).  Have you *looked* at `genSol` in the addendum?  That's as general a solution as you're going to get *but it is not what you asked for in your question*.

Comment: Eric Towers but how i see up y[0]==1 we will get complex solution, so throw point (0,1) there isnt real solution ?

Comment: @МилошВучковић : `genSol /. {d -> 0, c -> 1}`.

Comment: I see, it's great, just can you explain me abit what that function doing excactly, how it get only reals solutions and do i need when i explaining that last function , that what you made upper ?

Comment: @МилошВучковић : I've added some text about the function of `ComplexExpand[]`.  You might benefit from looking at `genSol` and thinking about what is happening when we specialize `d` to zero and `c` to one.

Comment: so can we tell that last picture is atleast picture of (reals) General Solution ?

Comment: @МилошВучковић : The last picture is a smpling of real solutions.  A graph of all real solutions is a solid plane since every point is a point on a particular solution.